# How can I add a top level to an existing dictionary from values of the dictionary and thus make it nested?

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

How can I add one dictionary to another dictionary by creating a nested dictionary while using an existing key as the key on the top level of the resulting nested dictionary?

Assume I have something like this:

```
dict1 = {'key1': 11, 'key2': 12, 'key_id':, 'id1'}
dict2 = {'key1': 21, 'key2': 22, 'key_id':, 'id2'}
```

and I want to end up with something like

```
dict_final = {'id1':{'key1': 11, 'key2': 12, 'key_id':, 'id1'}, 'id2': {'key1': 21, 'key2': 22, 'key_id':, 'id2'}}
```

`dict1.update(dict2)` would only overwrite the values in dict1; How can I tell python to add a new top level in an exisiting dictionary?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most straightforward way is like this:

```
dict_final = {
    dict1["key_id"]: dict1,
    dict2["key_id"]: dict2,
}
```

Or add them one at a time:

```
dict_final = {}
dict_final[dict1["key_id"]] = dict1
dict_final[dict2["key_id"]] = dict2
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `dict` to merge a list of tuples together.
With that in mind, you can use zip + dict

```
dict1 = {'key1': 11, 'key2': 12, 'key_id': 'id1'}
dict2 = {'key1': 21, 'key2': 22, 'key_id': 'id2'}


outer_keys = ['id1', 'id2'];
dicts = [dict1, dict2]

d = dict(zip(outer_keys, dicts))
print(dict(d))
```